# Code run multiple times when calling self

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use this login on a bigger project but i can simulate the problem with this piece of code. With this class i want to update the counter in order to have access on the updated counter from another methon using an eventListener, for the purpose of this example i will print the counter in order to see the behaviour.

```
class Test {

  private counter: nubmer = 0;
  private add: Element;
  private remove: Element;

  constructor(){
    this.add = document.getElementById('btn');
    this.remove = document.getElementById('btn2');
    this.start();
  }

  public print(): void {
    console.log(this.counter);
  }

  public start(): void {

    this.add.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.counter += 1;
      this.start();
    });

    this.remove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.counter -= 1;
      this.start();
    });

    this.print();

  }
}
```

Html page with the two buttons

```
<button id="btn">Add</button>
<button id="btn2">Remove</button>
```

The problem with this implementation is that every time i click add or remove button the code runs one time first, two times with the second click, four times with third etc.

Comment: you're calling `start` on click, and `start` hooks up events every time it's called

Comment: What's the best practice if i want to perform an action (example: to update a counter) when i hit click and then to use the updated counter inside start() for another event?

Comment: Once you've hooked the event, it fires on *every* click, not just once. That's why it's an event. You're saying "I want to be notified every time <event> happens from now on." The way you wrote it you said: for every click, add another handler. So you double the amount of handlers with every click, and start getting more and more and more notifications with each click.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding additional event listeners every time there is a click...

```
this.add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.counter += 1;
  this.start(); // <-- this is the problem
});
```

Solution - I think you want to call `print`, not `start`:

```
class Test {

  private counter: nubmer = 0;
  private add: Element;
  private remove: Element;

  constructor(){
    this.add = document.getElementById('btn');
    this.remove = document.getElementById('btn2');
    this.start();
  }

  public print(): void {
    console.log(this.counter);
  }

  public start(): void {

    this.add.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.counter += 1;
      this.print();
    });

    this.remove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.counter -= 1;
      this.print();
    });

    this.print();

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that i can call print inside the event listener, but if i want to run another function instead of  print? For example i'm  updating the counter on click and i want to pass the updated counter with another eventlistener. How to implement this?

Comment: In the event of adding an additional event listener, both the existing and the new event listener will run (which was the behaviour you created before). So you need to remove the existing event listener before adding a new one. For example `this.add.removeEventListener(...)`. You need to exactly match the arguments used in `addEventListener` for the removal to work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Remove `this.start();` from your event listeners.

The problem is that you are rebinding on `start`

```
public start(): void {

this.add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.counter += 1;
  this.start();
});

this.remove.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.counter -= 1;
  this.start();
});

this.print();

 }
```

`this.start();` is being called every time you click the buttons. `start()` contains `this.add.addEventListener` which is adding *another* click binding.

Comment: Why javascript add another click binding?i hit the button once.how can unbind the event after the first click?

Comment: It's binding because `this.remove.addEventListener` is literally adding another event listener, so they keep piling up. Does `start()` need to be called on every click? Why not just remove the `this.start()` calls from the click binding? Just from glancing at your code, everything should work exactly the same without these calls. You can remove listeners with `.removeEventListener("click", [function])` but then you'd have to define a named function, not an anonymous function (the `() => {}` you're using here). I'd say just remove the `this.start()` from your listeners though.